# Difficulty creating spark.sql.Row from text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've tried:

```
val textLines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file.txt")
val rowRDD = Row.fromSeq(textLines.map(_.split(",")))
```

However, I'm getting the error 
`type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]
 required: Seq[Any]`

How can i fix the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to load a **CSV** into a **DataFrame**, there's a simpler way:

```
val dataframe: DataFrame = spark.read.csv("file.text")
```

Alternatively, if you're truly interested in converting an `RDD[String]` into an `RDD[Row]` - here's how you'd do that:

```
val rows: RDD[Row] = textLines.map(_.split(",")).map {
  a: Array[_] => Row(a: _*)
}
```

But note that this might create "uneven" rows (if your data isn't a proper CSV, different rows might have different number of columns, which would make this RDD pretty unusable).

Answer (score 1):

Map is a Higher Order Function function. The return value is always wrapped the the type on which you are applying map function

> Example :- List("Answer","Question","StackOverFlow").map(x =>
>   x.length)

Then this map function applied on String value but returns the Int Value but this is wrapped on List i.e. `List[String] => List[Int]`

Here Your map is applied on `textLines` which is of Type RDD[String]
Then you have applied map over `RDD[String]` that return `RDD[Array[String]]`
not `Array[String]`

You just need to use collect() method  like;

```
val textLines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file.txt")
val wordsArray = textLines.flatMap(_.split(",")).collect
val rowRDD = Row.fromSeq(wordsArray)
```

I am using `collect()` method that will returns you `Array[String]` and i am using `flatMap` instead of `map` because `flatMap` Flattens the value
otherwise on collect() you will get `Array[Array[String]]`
you can use map if it fits your scenario.

Hope this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd also ask why you are trying to create a Row out of text file like this? Since you are parsing a CSV file, perhaps [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) would help you work on a higher level.